# Boostrap modal renders multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

In my Table component, I'm using Vue Bootstrap's `b-table` component to create a table, which retrieves its' data from an external JSON file through Vuex. Now I also have another component, Actions, which is rendered on each row of the table. This component contains an edit button which is supposed to open a modal when clicked.

The problem is that whenever I click the edit button, 4 modals come up one on top of another. The issue seems to lie in the number of rows rendered, because in the JSON file, there are 4 objects, each of which contains the student's name, date of birth and so on. When I get rid of three of these objects, the modal only renders once. My conclusion is that the modal is rendering 4 times, for each row, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Here's the Table and Actions component:

```js
<script>
import Actions from "./Actions.vue"

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            fields: [
                'index',
                'full_name',
                { key: "date_of_birth", label: 'Date of Birth' },
                'municipality',
                { key: "action", label: 'Action' }
            ],
            // tableItems: this.$store.state.registeredStudents.registeredStudents
        }
    },

    components: {
        Actions
    },

    methods: {
        generateIndex() {
            return Math.floor(1000000 * Math.random()).toString().slice(0, 6);
        }
    },

    computed: {
        rows() {
            return this.tableItems.length
        },

        tableItems() {
            const registeredStudents = this.$store.state.registeredStudents.registeredStudents

            return registeredStudents.map(student => ({
                index: this.generateIndex(), ...student
            }))
        }
    },

    
}
</script>

<template>
    <b-table :fields="fields" :items="tableItems" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" responsive="sm" primary-key="index"
        striped hover>
        <template #cell(action)="data">
            <Actions/>
        </template>
    </b-table>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { BIconPencilFill, BIconTrashFill } from 'bootstrap-vue';

export default {

}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <b-button variant="primary" class="mx-1 p-1" v-b-modal.edit-student>
            <b-icon-pencil-fill></b-icon-pencil-fill>
        </b-button>
        <b-modal id="edit-student" title="Edit student info">
            <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
        </b-modal>
        <b-button variant="danger" class="mx-1 p-1">
            <b-icon-trash-fill></b-icon-trash-fill>
        </b-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is most likely because your id's are not unique. For each row of your table you are generating the following;

```html
<b-modal id="edit-student" title="Edit student info">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
</b-modal>
```

with the same ID.

I think the best approach here would be to include the Actions in the Table component. You don't need the extra component since it has no internal logic or props.

Table.vue

```js
data() {
        return {
            fields: [
                'index',
                'full_name',
                { key: "date_of_birth", label: 'Date of Birth' },
                'municipality',
                { key: "action", label: 'Action' }
            ],
            lastClickedRowIndex: -1
        }
    },
    ...

<template>
    <b-table :fields="fields" :items="tableItems" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" responsive="sm" primary-key="index"
        striped hover>
        <template #cell(action)="data">
          <b-button variant="primary" class="mx-1 p-1" @click="() => (lastClickedRowIndex = data.index)" v-b-modal.edit-student>
            <b-icon-pencil-fill></b-icon-pencil-fill>
          </b-button>
          <b-button variant="danger" class="mx-1 p-1">
            <b-icon-trash-fill></b-icon-trash-fill>
          </b-button>
        </template>
    </b-table>
    <b-modal id="edit-student" title="Edit student info">
        <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
        <!-- Dynamically change contents here based on lastClickedRowIndex -->
    </b-modal>
</template>
```

I apologise if any syntax is incorrect I've only used Vue 3.